# issue with using Ion android networking library

Tags: android, web-services, http, android-ion

I am working on android web application. 
When I am calling web service using simple HttpPost method.
where url is

```
http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/api/UploadFile/InsertFolder?userID=2039&folderName=issue&parentFolder=0
```

Using simple http

```
String url = "http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/api/UploadFile/InsertFolder?
userID=2039&folderName=issue&parentFolder=0"

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
responseText = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Every thing works fine with this Http methods.

But when I try to do this using [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion) android library. Using below code.

```
Ion.with(context)
                .load("POST", "http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/api/UploadFile/InsertFolder")
                .setLogging("LOG-POST",Log.VERBOSE)
                .setHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
                .setBodyParameter("userID","2039")
                .setBodyParameter("folderName","TEST post")
                .setBodyParameter("parentFolder","0")
                .asString()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Error downloading file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Download completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.d("RESULT",result);
                    }
                });
```

It returns following message.

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/api/UploadFile/InsertFolder'."}
```

I read many issue on Ion's official github repo. And tried almost solutions but still error is not solved.

What's wrong here?

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        json.addProperty("userID","2039");
        json.addProperty("folderName","temp0011");
        json.addProperty("parentFolder","0");

        Ion.with(context)
                .load("POST", "http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/api/UploadFile/InsertFolder")
                .setLogging("ion-geny",Log.DEBUG)
                .setHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
                .setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache")
                .setJsonObjectBody(json)
                .asString()
                .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                        if (e != null){
                            Log.e("Error Result", e.toString());
                        }
                        Log.d("Result", result);
                    }
                });
```

**Logcat:**

```
D/ion-geny﹕ (0 ms) http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/api/UploadFile/InsertFolder?userID=2039: preparing request
D/ion-geny﹕ (0 ms) http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/api/UploadFile/InsertFolder?userID=2039: preparing request
I/ion-geny﹕ (0 ms) http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/api/UploadFile/InsertFolder?userID=2039: Using loader: com.koushikdutta.ion.loader.HttpLoader@42656120
D/ion-geny﹕ (0 ms) http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/api/UploadFile/InsertFolder?userID=2039: Executing request.
D/ion-geny﹕ (6611 ms) http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/api/UploadFile/InsertFolder?userID=2039: Response is not cacheable
D/ion-geny﹕ (6615 ms) http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/api/UploadFile/InsertFolder?userID=2039: Connection successful
D/ion-geny﹕ (8592 ms) http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/api/UploadFile/InsertFolder?userID=2039: Recycling keep-alive socket
```

**Response:**

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/api/UploadFile/InsertFolder?userID=2039'."}
```

Comment: The request is succeeding, Your server is returning a 404 message json on the URL that you are posting to.

Comment: @koush Hi, first of all thanks for creating Ion.It's wonderful.  Here I have updated my code & also attached logcat & server response. Is there any problem with my code or problem is with the webservice?

Comment: It's probably an issue with the webservice or how you are invoking or handling that request.

Comment: solved problem. posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the bodyparameter in webservice. It's accepting whole as QueryString. And need to set HttpHeader "Content-Length = 0".Here below is my changed code.

```
     Ion.with(context)
                    .load("POST", "http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx/api/UploadFile/InsertFolder?
userID=2039&folderName=temp0011&parentFolder=0")
                    .setLogging("ion-geny",Log.DEBUG)
                    .setHeader("Content-Length","0")
                    .asString()
                    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                            if (e != null) {
                                Log.e("Error Result", e.toString());
                            }
                            Log.d("Result", result);
                        }
                    });
```

It's now working.

Comment: You can also probably do setStringBody("") to set that parameter.

Comment: .setStringBody("userID=2039&folderName=temp0013&parentFolder=0")

Comment: Depending on your service, it may be parsing either url encoded params or query string. If url encoded params, use setBodyParameter